# MySQL update reorder data fields

Tags: mysql

How can I reorder the fields in the table during an update.

i.e i have this table:

```
|id|order|
|1 | 0   |
|2 | 0   |
|3 | 1   |
|4 | 2   |
|5 | 3   |
|6 | 0   |
|7 | 4   |
```

Now what I want to do is that if id = 3 is deleted the whole order field would be updated to:

```
|id|order|
|1 | 0   |
|2 | 0   |
|4 | 1   |
|5 | 2   |
|6 | 0   |
|7 | 3   |
```

Is there a simple solution for this? If there is, how would I do it? I was thinking of checking the fields individually.

i.e if 3 is deleted I would fetch first its order number and check if there are no other id's that hold the same order and if there are none I would proceed to check all the order greater than the order number of id 3 and update them individually.

Comment: What would you do if `id = 2` gets deleted? What would be the output in your example?

Comment: @MostyMostacho it wont update the order, since order 0 is used by 2 id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the id is autonumeric or new ids will always take the max(id)+1 value then :

By updating all the rows after the one you just deleted :

```
update your_table set order = order - 1 where id> @the_id_you_just_deleted
```

Comment: This won't work. You are assuming it is sorted by id and that is not the case as he could insert a higher id in the middle (between `2` and `3` in the first example)

Comment: it seems that way with the data sample in the question. But i will precise it in my answer anyway. Thanks.

Comment: then : update your_table set order = order - 1 where id>=@the_id_you_just_deleted